# Meaning of "hazzas"

Tags: meaning

In a steam engine museum I came across the word "hazzas" and, although I can guess its meaning from the context, I could not find a definition for it.

A description portrayed a train whose first arrival would be greeted by "loud ***hazzas*** of the multitude only overpowered by the louder blowing of the locomotive steam whistles."

Comment: What country was this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that a "hazza" (an exclamation of joy not unlike "hooray" or "hurrah") would come from people gathered on the platform observing the train's arrival, their sound being overwhelmed by the train's whistles. Merriam Webster and the Oxford English Dictionary spell it "huzzah" but I'd suggest in this context they are one and the same. See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/huzzah.